# Create XSLT elements where the used use-attribute-set is depending on an attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt

The following XSLT Code works but i want to avoid the redundant occurrence of these five line:

```
    <xsl:element name="TextBlock" use-attribute-sets="Heading2">
      <xsl:call-template name="process-element">
        <xsl:with-param name="attr" select="'text|Text'" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:element>
```

The only thing that differs is the used attribute set. The attribute set depends on the LabelWrapper.theme attribute. i already tried to use variables but no luck.

**Questions:**

> How can i avoid the redundant lines of code?
>
> Is there a better solution todo so?

**XSL Stylesheet:**

```
  <xsl:template match="LabelWrapper">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="./@theme = 'Heading1'">
        <xsl:element name="TextBlock" use-attribute-sets="Heading1">
          <xsl:call-template name="process-element">
            <xsl:with-param name="attr" select="'text|Text'" />
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:when>
      
      <xsl:when test="./@theme = 'Emphasis'">
        <xsl:element name="TextBlock" use-attribute-sets="Heading2">
          <xsl:call-template name="process-element">
            <xsl:with-param name="attr" select="'text|Text'" />
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:when>
      
      <xsl:when test="./@theme = 'Title'">
        <xsl:element name="TextBlock" use-attribute-sets="Title">
          <xsl:call-template name="process-element">
            <xsl:with-param name="attr" select="'text|Text'" />
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:when>

      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:element name="TextBlock" use-attribute-sets="Normal">
          <xsl:call-template name="process-element">
            <xsl:with-param name="attr" select="'text|Text'" />
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:otherwise>      
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

the (simplified) xml input looks like this:

```
<LabelWrapper id="lblHeader" text="Big Header" theme="Heading1" />
<LabelWrapper id="lblHeader" text="normal text" theme="Normal" />
<LabelWrapper id="lblHeader" text="page title" theme="Title" />
<LabelWrapper id="lblHeader" text="Small Header " theme="Heading2" />
```

used attribute sets (sample)

```
  <xsl:attribute-set name="Heading1">
    <xsl:attribute name="FontFamily">Segoe UI</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="FontSize">30px</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="FontStyle">Normal</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="FontWeight">Normal</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:attribute-set>

  <xsl:attribute-set name="Heading2">
    <xsl:attribute name="FontFamily">Segoe UI</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="FontSize">16px</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="FontStyle">Normal</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="FontWeight">Bold</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:attribute-set>
```

Comment: I think you should post an input XML sample as well as the corresponding output you want to create with XSLT, then it is easier for us to make suggestions on how to shorten the code. With the information provides so far I wonder whether the `xsl:when test` shouldn't be replaced by `xsl:template match`. But as your question is mainly about the shortening of the repeated use of `use-attribute-sets`, I am not sure there is a way as that attribute value does not allow an XPath expression but simply a static list of qualified names.

Comment: added xml test input and an example of the used attribute sets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i solved the problem by splitting the template into two parts. The first for the general transformation

```
  <xsl:template match="LabelWrapper">
    <xsl:element name="TextBlock">
      <xsl:call-template name="process-element">
        <xsl:with-param name="attr" select="'text|Text'" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```

and the second for the attribute sets.

```
<xsl:template match="LabelWrapper/@theme|TextBoxWrapper/@theme|RadioButtonWrapper/@theme|CheckBoxWrapper/@theme" mode="to-attr">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test=". = 'Heading1'">
        <xsl:attribute name="FontFamily">Segoe UI</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="FontSize">30px</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="FontStyle">Normal</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="FontWeight">Normal</xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:when>

      <xsl:when test=". = 'Heading2'">
        <xsl:attribute name="FontFamily">Segoe UI</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="FontSize">16px</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="FontStyle">Normal</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="FontWeight">Bold</xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:when>

      <xsl:when test=". = 'Title'">
        <xsl:attribute name="FontFamily">Segoe UI Light</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="FontSize">23px</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="FontStyle">Normal</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="FontWeight">Normal</xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:when>

      <xsl:when test=". = 'Emphasis'">
        <xsl:attribute name="FontFamily">Segoe UI</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="FontSize">12px</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="FontStyle">Normal</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="FontWeight">Bold</xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:when>

      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:attribute name="FontFamily">Segoe UI</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="FontSize">12px</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="FontStyle">Normal</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="FontWeight">Normal</xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```